# Discord.js returns an undefined error when creating a Client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I followed the example on the official discord.js guide and it gave the code:

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

But upon running it gave this error:

```
D:\DiscCoin\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildManager.js:39
    if (!cacheWarningEmitted && this._cache.constructor.name !== 'Collection') {
                                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at new GuildManager (D:\DiscCoin\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildManager.js:39:57)
    at new Client (D:\DiscCoin\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:127:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DiscCoin\index.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I have not done anything besides follow the official guide. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This error was brought up a few days ago on the [Discord.JS Github](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/6898), it turned out to be a regression with `@discordjs/collection` ([link to the comment](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/6898#issuecomment-952501673))

One of the maintainers suggested running [this](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/6898#issuecomment-952542554):

`npm i @discordjs/collection`

If that doesn't work, you can try deleting your `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the module/s.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30188012)

Comment: It does answer it. @V-rundPuro-hit